# How do I get a Range of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone from a tstzrange column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a [`tstzrange` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html). Rails is translating it into a `Range` of `Time` objects which loses the time zone information. I would like a `Range` of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` objects. How can I do that?

Alternatively, how can I check if `tstzrange` spans exactly a day in the current time zone, and what day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ActiveRecord::Timestamp docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html)...

> You can also add database specific timezone aware types. For example, for PostgreSQL:
>
> ```
> ActiveRecord::Base.time_zone_aware_types += [:tsrange, :tstzrange]
> ```

---

[`in_time_zone`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-in_time_zone) will turn a `Time` into `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` in the application's time zone. A Range of Times can be turned into a Range of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone like so:

```
range = Range.new(
  tstzrange.begin.in_time_zone,
  tstzrange.end.in_time_zone,
  # Taking care to preserve whether the range is inclusive or exclusive.
  tstzrange.exclude_end?
)
```